# PHP choose the side a die has?

Tags: php, dice

The php section of my code is not doing the correct operations
when the user submits his/her number, for example, if the user submits 5, I want the rand function to randomly output 5 as the number selected; however, my code sometimes works and at other times does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">


<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<title>
choose a die number
</title>
</head>
<center>
<body>
<h1>Choose a die number</h1>
<form method = "post" action="choosedie.php"/>
<!--If the user selects a number of sides the die is suppose to have
rand should go through and pick the number randomly, and echo out the 
number that was entered by the user-->

Please choose how many sides a die should have from 1 through 6:
<br/>
<input type = "text" name = "roll"/>
<?php


//Roll a random dice from 1 through 6:
$roll = rand(1,6);
// Add random variable to do comparison on.
```

Is there a way for me to just compare rand here, without having to create another variable?

```
$random  = rand(1,6);

// If $roll is equal to $random echo the output out to the user.
If ($roll == $random)
{
echo "<br/>Here is the random $roll with the appropriate maximum value $random\n";
```

If the user selects 5, I want this to echo out 5, but I am getting different values?

```
}


?>


</body>
</center>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **think** what you're trying to do here is ask the user to input how many sides the die has and then output what the value is? The question doesn't make a lot of sense... but if the above is what you're trying to do, this should work:

**choosedie.php**

```
<h1>Choose a die number</h1>
<form method = "post" action="choosedie.php"/> 
Please choose how many sides a die should have from 1 through 6:
<br/>
<input type="text" name="roll"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["roll"])) {
  $roll = rand(1, $_POST["roll"]);
  printf("A %s was rolled, with a maximum roll of %s", $roll, $_POST["roll"]);
}
?>
```

This will allow the user to input the number of sides a die has, and then print out what was rolled along with the number of sides.

Comment: Even though the question does not make a lot of sense you where able to get what I was asking from the user, that's pretty leet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Since `rand(n,m)` returns an integer value, you should be able to do thusly:

```
if(rand(1,6) == $guess){
    echo "Congratulations - your guess of $guess was right!";
}
else{
    echo "No dice - better luck next time.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that really clarified how to manipulate and use rand with the if and else construct to do a comparison.

Comment: happy it's what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Each time this page is loaded, it will pick two random numbers, $random and $roll, and if they are equal, print them.

If you want to get the users input, you'll need to use $_POST.

```
$users_dice_roll = $_POST["roll"];
$random_dice_roll = rand(1,6);
if($random_dice_roll == $users_dice_roll){
    echo "You rolled: $users_guess";
}
```

Also, don't you need a submit button?